# Parsing Time Variabale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a time stamp that i'm using for the x-axis of my line charts, as of now i'm just passing it as "2018-11-29T20:32:24.025Z" I would like to clean this up to only display the day, hour, and minute. It looks like Moment.js is a popular library for this, but i'm having some problems formatting it.

Failed Attempt

```
let parsedDate = moment(parsedData.published_at,'DD--hh--mm')
```

Comment: The string "DD--hh--mm" does not describe your actual date string format. That format string is for *parsing* the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you can pass your `inputDate` (ie `2018-11-29T20:32:24.025Z`) directly to the moment constructor.

Doing this will give you a moment object for that `inputDate` string, and from that you can call [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) with your `DD--hh--mm` pattern to format the required string:

```js
let inputDate = "2018-11-29T20:32:24.025Z";

// Create a moment object from input string
let parsedDate = moment(inputDate);

// Format a string from moment, based on the required pattern
let formattedData = parsedDate.format('DD--hh--mm');

console.log(formattedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to

1. Parse the date

   ```
   let parsedDate = moment(parsedData.published_at);
   ```
2. Format the date

   ```
   let formattedDate = parsedDate.format(...
   ```

   See [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).